# SQL trazer resultado com números repetidos da coluna todos somente o maior

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ola pessoal estou tentando buscar um dado porém não estou conseguindo filtrar da maneira que preciso, exemplo :

```
select a.cod, a.nome, b.pedido, b.versao from cliente a 
inner join pedido b On a.cod= b.cod
order by b.pedido
```

Agora o problema uma versao tem mais de uma tipo

ABaixo o exemplo de como está vindo o resultado:

esse foi o resultado mais só traz agora se eu colocar o orçamento  caso o orçamento esteja null a pessoa coloca a data inicial e final. Mais quando coloco agora ele traz tudo desconsiderando o comando

ai ele traz certo se colocar a cotação.
 Se colocar por data inicial e final nas variáveis ele volta a trazer tudo sem considerar a ultima versão.

Comment: Versão 3 seria pedido 3?
O Resultado da sua query não condiz com o SQL que você postou.

Comment: Ola esse e só um exemplo básico para figurar. Um pedido pode ter mais versões então não pode ser fixo 3 , igual no exemplo ele tem várias versões até virar pedido no caso só quero que ele traga tudo da última versão

Comment: Jameson: poste o resultado da execução do código que transcreveu. E acrescente informações sobre a tabela PEDIDO; por exemplo, outras colunas que influenciam no resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que tenha um erro no seu `scrip` pois, **aparentemente**, você compara o código do pedido com o código do cliente no `join`, veja `inner join pedido b On` **`a.cod= b.cod`**

Você pode adicionar um `AND` no seu `join` que irá filtrar pelo `MAX` versão, veja

```
select 
    a.cod, 
    a.nome, 
    b.pedido, 
    b.versao 
from cliente a 
    inner join pedido b On a.cod= b.codigo_cliente AND b.versao = (select max(pedido.versao) from pedido where pedido.codigo_cliente = a.id)
order by b.pedido
```

Para referencia fiz um exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b85bc/1)

---

**EDIT**

O que estou vendo de errado são as verificações com `isnull`, nelas você diz que se o campo for nulo, retorna ele mesmo (`ISNULL (@vORCV_COD , @vORCV_COD)`) não faz sentido isso.

Tente a seguinte query:

```
DECLARE
    @vORCV_COD INT ,
    @vDAT_INI CHAR(10),
    @vDAT_FIM CHAR(10)

SET @vORCV_COD =  null-- 333829
SET @vDAT_INI = '20180405' --data inicial
SET @vDAT_FIM = '20180501' -- data final

SELECT 
    A.ORCV_COD, 
    A.VEOV_VAL,
    A.VEOV_QTT_VER ,
    A.VEOV_PER_MARLUC,
    E.PARC_COD,
    A.PEDS_COD,
    I.PEDS_DAT_CAD,
    A.VEOV_DAT_CAD,
    V.VEND_NOM_FAN,
    B.AORC_OBS,
    B.AORC_DAT_CAD,
    C.USUA_NOM,
    D.TAOR_NOM,
    F.STOV_NOM,
    ISNULL(G.PARC_NOM_RAZ, J.PAOV_NOM_EMP) AS 'RAZAO SOCIAL',
    ISNULL(H.OROV_NOM, 'ORIGEM NÃO INDICADA') AS 'ORIGEM'
FROM TCOM_VERORV A 
    LEFT JOIN TCOM_ANDORC B         ON A.ORCV_COD = B.ORCV_COD 
    LEFT JOIN TCOM_TIPANDORC D      ON D.TAOR_COD = B.TAOR_COD
    INNER JOIN TCOM_ORCVEN E        ON E.ORCV_COD  = A.ORCV_COD
    INNER JOIN TCOM_STAORV F        ON  E.STOV_COD = F.STOV_COD
    LEFT JOIN TACE_USUARIO C        ON C.USUA_COD  = B.USUA_COD          
    INNER JOIN TCOM_VENDEDOR V      ON V.VEND_COD = E.VEND_COD
    LEFT JOIN TCOM_PARCEIRO G       ON G.PARC_COD = E.PARC_COD
    LEFT JOIN TCOM_ORIORV H         ON H.OROV_COD = E.OROV_COD
    LEFT JOIN TCOM_PEDSAI I         ON I.PEDS_COD = A.PEDS_COD
    LEFT JOIN TCOM_PARORV J         ON A.ORCV_COD = J.ORCV_COD
WHERE (1=1)
    AND ISNULL(A.ORCV_COD, 0) = ISNULL (@vORCV_COD , ISNULL(A.ORCV_COD, 0)) 
    AND A.VEOV_QTT_VER = (SELECT MAX(X.VEOV_QTT_VER) FROM TCOM_VERORV X WHERE ISNULL(X.ORCV_COD, 0) = ISNULL(A.ORCV_COD, 0))
    AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), ORCV_DAT_CAD , 112) BETWEEN ISNULL (@vDAT_INI, CONVERT(CHAR(10), ORCV_DAT_CAD , 112)) AND ISNULL (@vDAT_FIM, CONVERT(CHAR(10), ORCV_DAT_CAD , 112))
```

Explicação:

Além de arrumar a indentação, a única coisa que alterei de fato foi o `where`
nos `isnull`, caso seja nulo a variável ele deve comparar com ele mesmo, e caso o campo seja nulo, vai comparar 0 com 0.

Comment: Quem deu o **Down Vote** poderia ao menos explicar o motivo?

Comment: ola, obrigado pela ajuda da maneira que você fez conseguir resultados porem só não estou conseguindo trazer por data vou melhora o exemplo acima, para ver se o senhor pode me auxiliar

Comment: @Jameson não entendi direito, no caso ele pode ter versões nulas?

Comment: Ola não, tem as variáveis de de orçamento e datIni e final se a pessoa não colocar a cotação vai colocar as datas . as versões não são nulas todos orçamentos tem mais os orçamentos tem mais de uma versão . o exemplo q VC deu funcionou colocando o número só orçamento mais se deixo nulo e tento procurar pelas datas ele traz todas versões desprezando o q eu fiz com o exemplo q VC me

Comment: Passou.  Na subquery q VC passou acho q precisa trazer as variáveis das datas   , mais desse jeito não conseguir resultado parece que faz um loop q não fica vários minutos la

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas pelo que vi no print que vc colocou na pergunta, você usa um **`OR`**, não deveria ser **`AND`**. Outra coisa, evite usar imagens, é melhor se colocar seu código como texto.

Comment: Então tentei também usar o AND. mais nada tb vou ver se consigo postar e porque não estava conseguindo formatar o código aqui. Mais ali na subquery daria para colocar a data que quero ?

Comment: É possível sim, adicione a `query` toda que tentamos deixar ela como você quer ;)

Comment: Olá, postei o código todo que estou implementando  como o exemplo que você sugeriu deu certo colocando o filtro de cotação mais se deixo em branco e filtro por data ele traz normal sem filtrar as ultimas cotações.

Comment: ainda não conseguir. Com o segundo AND  ele não traz resultado se coloco OR ele traz todos os registros e todas versões não somente a ultima ,e se busca pelo orçamento traz resultado normal do jeito que preciso

Comment: A data que vc está pesquisando tem dados?

Comment: Sim tem, normal.

Comment: Vamos para o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77652/discussion-between-jameson-and-barbetta)

Comment: deu certo muito. Obrigado pela paciência.

Comment: Imagina, estamos ai para isso ;)

Answer (score 1):

O que compreendi é que para cada pedido deve-se retornar a linha com a última versão. Há algumas formas de obter esse resultado; eis uma delas:

```
-- código #1
with PedidoClassificado as (
SELECT cod, pedido, versao,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by pedido order by versao desc)
  from pedido
)
SELECT B.cod, A.nome, B.pedido, B.versao
  from cliente as A 
       inner join PedidoClassificado as B on A.cod = B.cod
  where B.seq = 1;
```

Comment: Vou tentar  aqui

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o comando WHERE do SQL como abaixo:

```
select 
     a.cod, 
     a.nome, 
     b.pedido, 
     b.versao 
from cliente a 
inner join pedido b 
   ON a.cod= b.cod
where b.versao = 3
order by b.pedido;
```

Comment: Não e isso, isso sei fazer o que presico e trazer os as últimas versões dos pedidos, nem todo pedido só tem 3 versões pode ter 1 ou 10 até virar pedido aprovado,